# Counter for array causing illegal start of expression

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a class, "vehicle" which should allow the array to be saved with the information input by the user but when I try and get the method to accept the data with the counter giving each data entry a unique number it doesn't accept anything past the [ on `vehicle vehiclearray[totalcount] = new vehiclearray(count,licence,date,value,colour);` I'm relatively new to java and this problem has stumped me, any help would be appreciated.

This is the whole code, the problem is under submenu1.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int option = menu();
        int totalcount = submenu1.totalcount;
        int carcount = submenu1.carcount;
        int bikecount = submenu1.bikecount;
        vehicle vehiclearray[] = new vehiclearray[100];

        if (option == 1)
            submenu1(vehiclearray);
        else if (option ==2)
            submenu2(totalcount, vehiclearray);
        else if (option ==3)
            submenu3(totalcount, carcount, bikecount,museumbike, museumcar);
        else if (option ==4)
            submenu4(carcount, museumcar);
        else if (option ==5)
            submenu5(bikecount, museumbike);
        else if (option ==6)
            System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid selection, please try again.");
    }
}

class menusystem
{
    public static int menu()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int option = 0;

        System.out.println("Please select an option");
        System.out.println("=======================");
        System.out.println("1. Add a vehicle to the collection");
        System.out.println("2. List vehices manufactured by a specifit year");
        System.out.println("3. List all vehcles of a certain engine size or more");
        System.out.println("4. list all cars");
        System.out.println("5. List all bikes");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");
        option = input.nextInt();
        return option;
    }

    public static int submenu1(vehicle vehiclearray[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String suboption1;
        int totalcount = carcount = bikecount = 1;

        System.out.println("Is the vehicle a car or a bike? (exit to close)");
        suboption1 = input.next();
        while(!suboption1.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
        {
            if (suboption1.equalsIgnoreCase("car"))
            {
                vehicle.id=count;
                System.out.println("Please enter the licence, manufacture year, car value and colour of the car");
                vehicle vehiclearray[totalcount] = new vehiclearray(count,licence,date,value,colour);
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of doors, number of seats, engine type (petrol or deisol) and engine size in litres");
                museumcar museumcar[carcount] = new museumcar(cardoors,seats,enginetype,carenginesize);
                totalcount++;
                carcount++;

            }
            else if (suboption1.equalsIgnoreCase("bike"))
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter the licence, manufacture year, car value and colour of the bike");
                vehicle vehiclearray[totalcount] = new vehiclearray(licence,date,value,colour);
                vehicle.id=count;
                System.out.println("Please enter the bike type (sports, tourer or trials) and engine size in cc");
                museumbike museumbike[bikecount] = new museumbike(type,bikeenginesize);
                totalcount++;
                bikecount++;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid entry.");

                System.out.println("Is the vehicle a car or a bike? (exit to close)");
                suboption1 = input.next();
                return bikecount;
                return carcount;
                return totalcount;
        } 
    }

    public static void submenu2(int totalcount, vehicle vehiclearray[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int desiredyear = 0;
        int count = 1;

        System.out.println("What vehicle manufacture date do you want to see?");
        desiredyear = input.nextInt();
        for (count = 1; count <= totalcount; count++)
        {
            if (vehiclearray[totalcount].getdate == desiredyear)
                System.out.println(vehiclearray[totalcount] +" id : "+ vehiclearray[totalcount].getlicence(), +" licence : "+ vehiclearray[totalcount].getdate(), +" date : "+ vehiclearray[totalcount].getvalue(), +" value : "+ vehiclearray[totalcount].getcolour() +" colour:");
            else
                System.out.println(vehiclearray[totalcount] +" does not match the desired manufacture year");
        }
    }

    public static void submenu3(int totalcount, int carcount, int bikecount, museumbike museumbike[], museumcar museumcar[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        double desiredsize = 0;
        int count = 1;

        System.out.println("What vehicle size or more do you want to see?");
        desiredsize = input.nextDouble();
        for (count = 1; count <= totalcount; count++)
        {
            if (desiredsize >=0 && desiredsize <=100)
            {
                if (museumcar[carcount].getcarenginesize >= desiredsize)
                    System.out.println(museumcar[carcount].getcardoors(), +(" doors : ")+ museumcar[carcount].getseats(), +(" seats : ")+ museumcar[carcount].getenginetype(), +(" : ")+ museumcar[carcount].getcarenginesize() +("ltrs"));
                else
                    System.out.println("This car has a lower engine size then the desiredsize");
            }
            else if (desiredsize >=100)
                System.out.println(museumbike[bikecount].gettype(), +(" : ")+ museumbike[bikecount].getbikeenginesize() +("cc"));
        }
    }

    public static void submenu4(int carcount, museumcar museumcar[])
    {
        int count = 1;

        for (count = 1; count <= museumcar[carcount]; count++)
        {
            System.out.println(museumcar[carcount].getcardoors(), +(" doors : ")+ museumcar[carcount].getseats(), +(" seats : ")+ museumcar[carcount].getenginetype(), +(" : ")+ museumcar[carcount].getcarenginesize() +("ltrs"));
        }
    }

    public static void submenu5(int bikecount, museumbike museumbike[])
    {
        int count = 1;

        for (count = 1; count <= museumbike[bikecount]; count++)
        {
            System.out.println(("bike id:")+ museumbike[bikecount].gettype(), +(" : ")+ museumbike[bikecount].getbikeenginesize() +("cc"));
        }
    }
}

class vehicle
{
    private int carid;
    private String licence;
    private int date;
    private Double value;
    private String colour;


    vehicle (int i,String l, int d, double v, String c)
    {
        id = i;
        licence = l;
        date = d;
        value = v;
        colour = c;     
    }
    int getid()
    {
        return id;
    }

    String getlicence()
    {
        return licence;
    }

    int getdate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    Double getvalue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    String getcolour()
    {
        return colour;
    }
}

class museumcar extends vehicle
{
    private int cardoors;
    private int seats;
    private String enginetype;
    private Double carenginesize;


    museumcar (int cd, int s, String et, Double ces)
    {
        super (i, l, d, v, c);
        cardoors = cd;
        seats = s;
        enginetype = et;
        carenginesize = es;     
    }

    int getcardoors()
    {
        return cardoors;
    }

    int getseats()
    {
        return seats;
    }

    String getenginetype()
    {
        return enginetype;
    }

    Double getcarenginesize()
    {
        return carenginesize;
    }
}

class museumbike extends vehicle
{
    private String type;
    private Double bikeenginesize;  

    museumbike (String t, Double bes)
    {
        super (i, l, d, v, c);
        type = t;
        bikeenginesize = bes;       
    }

    String gettype()
    {
        return type;
    }

    Double getbikeenginesize()
    {
        return bikeenginesize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please check out edits to answer. If anything is unclear, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no vehiclearray class and so you can't do `new vehiclearray[...]`, but instead should do `new vehicle[...]`.

So for example, this line of code is not legal:

```
vehicle vehiclearray[] = new vehiclearray[100];
```

but this is:

```
vehicle vehiclearray[] = new vehicle[100];
```

In general I think that most of declare our variable with the array brackets on the class and not on the variable:

```
vehicle[] vehiclearray = new vehicle[100];
```

Although your way is legal (if you created the correct array object declaration that is).

Additional Notes:

- Your class names should start with a capital letter so as to comply with Java naming conventions so that others (us!) can better understand your code.
- If you have a question and your code doesn't compile, you should post any and all full compiler error messages with your question and also indicate which line(s) in your code cause the errors.

Comment: The array was causing one of the problems, like you said I hadn't initialized it correctly. Thanks for the in depth response.